# coverage.ec file generated by firebase test labs shows only coverage for Java files , it doesnot show for Kotlin files

Tags: android, kotlin, code-coverage, jacoco, firebase-test-lab

Hi my android app consist of both java and Kotlin files

I use
**./gradlew assembleSnapshotStaging** for app
**./gradlew :app:assembleAndroidTest** for test app

I am running my instrumentation test in firebase test labs via gcloud with coverage enabled from my terminal

`gcloud firebase test android run --app /Users/senthilvelp/sampleapp-android/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/sample-Debug-175.apk --test /Users/senthilvelp/sampleapp-android/app/build/outputs/apk/androidTest/debug/sample-debug-androidTest.apk --device model=blueline,version=28 --test-targets "class com.sampleapp.UITests.Tests.contacts.ContactTest" --environment-variables coverage=true,coverageFile="/sdcard/coverage.ec" --directories-to-pull /sdcard`

after the tests are finished. it has generated coverage file as **2020-12-21_15_31_57.950089_XyKR_blueline-28-en-portrait_artifacts_sdcard_coverage.ec**

I am renaming the file to .exec , then I open the file in **show coverage option under Run in Android studio** ,The Kotlin files coverage is not displayed in the report

Any help on this ?

if I run `./gradlew create${variantName.capitalize()}CoverageReport"` in my local machine it generates the coverage including Kotlin files

Comment: Did you find out the solution for this problem? Cheers

Comment: @NunesD. Nope , currently using the gradle command to visualise the report